# XAML click event handler not triggering

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, monogame

For some reason I cannot get the handler to trigger for the click function. When I click I get the "bing" sound as though I am doing something wrong. This is a Windows 8 app full screen. I feel as though the entire screen is disabled to mouse clicks. This is a MonoGame project which is nested inside a XAML interface. The code that controls the "Menu" of the game is as follows:

```
<StackPanel Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ListView Name="InGameMenu" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Orange" Height="auto" Padding="30 0 0 0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button FontSize="40" Content="{Binding}" Click="MenuElementSelected" IsEnabled="True"></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

The elements loaded into the list are just strings. Any ideas on what might be going on? The event handler is

```
    private void MenuElementSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button obj = sender as Button;

        switch ((string)obj.Content)
        {
            case "Resume":
                {
                    _game.resume();
                    break;
                }
            case "Restart":
                {
                    _game.restart();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

but it never even triggers a break point inside.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

EDIT:

The entire thing sits a SwapChainBackgroundPanel to transpose the MonoGame onto the interface. I am not sure yet, but this could be part of the issue.

Comment: I would try giving your button a name and then programmatically attaching the handler to the Click event in the code behind.  Then, manually invoke the Click event and try to step into it.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Same issue.

Comment: I am facing similar issue on one page
I have a button inside StackPanel which is not triggering the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you write a lot of code you tend to forget you have done certain things and worst of all you might miss obvious things sometimes. Reminder to all friendly programmers; pay better attention when you are trying to debug previous issues so they don't spill over into a new issue they might of created (unnoticed). I had the following line of code:

```
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().IsInputEnabled = false;
```

smack at the top of the page initialization and completely missed it. Hope this helps someone else who made this silly mistake. We write thousands of lines of code on a daily basis, so things like this can happen if you are not careful enough in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `switch` like below and insert a break point on the `default:` line. Then, observe what is the value of the `content` variable:

```
switch ((string)obj.Content)
{
    case "Resume":
        {
            _game.resume();
            break;
        }
    case "Restart":
        {
            _game.restart();
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            var content = (string)obj.Content;
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Already checked this because of the Button obj = sender as Button; in the top can have a break on it. I did check out your suggestion just in case, but same effect. Nothing. The event handler is never called.